# Equity curve assessment of 100% strategy to do position sizing with different strategy

Tags: pine-script

During my strategy creation in pine script I want to do dynamic position sizing, depending on the equity curve compared to its moving average.

This means I need to keep track of the imaginary behaviour of the strategy if it were to run as 100% orders.

I have tried to approximate the behaviour like this. Although I am not certain I did it right.

**Update:**

```
float lastTradeProfit = na

// if a strategy change is detected: 
if strategy.position_size != strategy.position_size[1]
    // save the change in profit, but correct for the fact that only half of the capital was used
    lastTradeProfit := (strategy.netprofit - strategy.netprofit[1]/strategy.netprofit[1])
    if (lastTradeProfit[1] < sma(lastTradeProfit, 20)[1])
        lastTradeProfit := lastTradeProfit * 2

// set the current order position
if (lastTradeProfit[1] < sma(lastTradeProfit, 20)[1])
    ordersize := 0.5 * ordersize
```

I feel like this is close, but it would work better if I can access the % change in order.

Comment: you can start from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68032797/11977284

Comment: Take each of the n-trades and mark them to market. [solved].

Comment: I use ``var`` to keep a track of it myself